# Lists inside list in C#

Tags: c#, list

It's my first time working with collections and Im stuck here, I made a test project to check it out and I encounter a problem I dont know how work around.

First, what I want to do in particular with lists (cant use anything else), is to have a  major list with integer lists inside, like this:

```
    List<List<int>> Allnums = new List<List<int>>();
```

The numbers I want to add to the previous list are collected here:

```
    List<int> nums = new List<int>();
```

So far, so good.

I need to add indefinitely times lists (nums) to my major list (Allnums), so I cant create nums1, nums2, num3... etc

Ok, lets try adding a random number to nums: (only 1 number for now)

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nums.Add(rnd.Next(10));
    }
```

Now, lets save the number that has been generated and clear the nums list to store new a new number next time (Lets store 4 lists only).

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Allnums.Add(nums); //adds the minor list to the major list.
        nums.Clear(); //clears the minor list to accept new values.
    }
```

Lets check the results with this code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Number of lists entered: " + Allnums.Count);
        foreach (List<int> numList in Allnums)
        {    
            listBox1.Items.Add("----------"); //separator to divide the lists
            foreach(int number in numList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(number);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get this:

```
Number of lists entered: 4 //OK
---------- //List1: nothing
---------- //List2: nothing
---------- //List3: nothing
---------- //List4: nothing
```

As you see, all the numbers generated are not in there.
But if I remove 'nums.Clear();' in 'button2_Click' event, I get this:

```
Number of lists entered: 4 //OK
---------- //List1
0
5
9
1
----------//List2
0
5
9
1
----------//List3
0
5
9
1
----------//List4
0
5
9
1
//All wrong
```

It stored all the values, but in a wrong way, because what I want to achieve is this:

```
Number of lists entered: 4
----------//List1
0
----------//List2
5
----------//List3
9
----------//List4
1
```

Am I wrong? Do I have to do something else? Please help, thanks for reading.

Comment: `List` is a reference type (similar to pointers in other languages). You need to `new List` again instead of `Clear` so that it is a *new* list.

Comment: `Allnums` is only keeping references to your other lists, and so when you `.Clear()` them, the data will be removed.  Keeping references to each of the `nums` lists in `Allnums` doesn't change that at all.  How exactly to fix this kind of depends on what you're trying to do.  What is the ultimate goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  As @crashmstr said, `List` is a reference type.  A better solution would be:

```
AllNums.Add(nums);
nums = new List<List<int>>();
```

=======================================================

In your `button2_Click` function, you need to create a copy of `nums` before adding it to Allnums.  Something like this would do the trick:

```
var newNums = nums.ToArray().ToList();
Allnums.Add(newNums);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you do `Allnums.Add(nums);` you have two references for your `nums`: one inside `Allnums`, and one inside your `nums`. When you add `nums` four times to `Allnums` you have 5 references pointing to the same list!

You have to create new list, i would suggest one of this solutions:

`Allnums.Add(new List<int>(nums))`

or

```
Allnums.Add(nums);
nums = new List<int>();
```

in your `button2_Click` method.